# Unable to Deploy PerformancePoint Dashboard Page to SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2007, performancepoint

I'm creating a PerformancePoint (henceforth PP) Dashboard that contains a web report to be deployed to the a SharePoint web application that I had created. I followed the instruction in the link below.

[Deploy a PerformancePoint dashboard to a SharePoint site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA102418591033.aspx)

In summary, following the instructions in the link, I published the Dashboard to the PP site. Then, I added my account in PP as *Creator* in the Application level, *Editor* in both the Dashboard and the Web Report. In the SharePoint site, I added my account under *Contributor*. I even added the *PerformancePointDefault.master* just to be sure.

Now, when I deploy my Dashboard to a Report Library, I was able deploy the folder for the Dashboard, but not the Dashboard Page file.

I googled for this, but I could not find any article helpful.

**UPDATE 2009-09-30**:
I was able to resolve the issue by creating another site collection. Maybe the first site collection is messed up.

Comment: Belongs on Server Fault http://serverfault.com. Also please give detail about the Dashboard Page file - does it not appear or is there an error?

Comment: Hi Alex,

1. I'm not sure why my question should be posted to Server Fault. I think the question is appropriate for this site because it involves development. Either way, if this is indeed a question for Server Fault, then I'll happily have the question posted there :).

2. Unfortunately, there's no error. Unexpectedly, the PP Designer indicates that the deployment was successful, but when I'm about to view the dashboard page, it did not appeared. Strange :(.

Comment: I thin kwhat Alex means is thast you should check the logs generated by SharePoint (be it the acutal log files or the WIndows Event Viewer) at the exact moment you are trying to open the dashboard. SharePoint is notorious for showing the (end)user an exact description of the error that occurred, if at all...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot about the log file. Silly me :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the EXACT same problem. I was about to take the best advice I could find and delete my site collection and create a new one from scratch, but by the grace of God, I had one final thought.

In our case, the site created was originally http://ServerName but we later added a host header (i.e. http://BiSite).  I had been deploying the dashboard using the host header the entire time, so I decided to try using the original name of the site using the server name and viola, the dashboard finally deployed correctly, pages and all.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish a dashboard in MOSS, you have to make sure that you select **Publish a Major Version** in the dashboard page's drop-down in the report library.

Why is this a community wiki?  Seems like there should be a right answer to this question...

Comment: Actually, I was not able to publish the dashboard on the site collection to begin with :)

Comment: ah.  I see.  Well, once you get it published, don't forget to do the major version thing.